# Runtime constraints on CPU and memory with docker containers

Tags: memory-management, docker, containers, cpu-usage

How can we change the memory and cpu limit for docker containers at runtime? I mean while the container is running I would like to change the the memory limit for example

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change that inside the running container, you would have to do that on your host.

How you do that on the host depends on your host-os, on Linux I suggest to take a look a **cgroups**, thats how docker internally restricts containers.

On **ubuntu** you could use the **cgroup manager cgm** (tried it on ubuntu 15.04).

1. create a new cgroup for cpu, move the process (e.g. 28433) to it and set a value

> ```
> > # cgm create cpu dudecpu 
> > # cgm movepid cpu dudecpu 28433 
> > # cgm setvalue cpu dudecpu cpu.shares 512
> ```

2. create a new cgroup for the memory move the process (e.g. 28433) to it and set a value

> ```
> > cgm create memory dudemem
> > cgm movepid memory dudemem 28433
> > cgm setvalue memory dudemem memory.limit_in_bytes 1000000000
> ```

3. check where your new cgroups are and look into these directories, you'll find all the properties of the cgroup there.

> ```
> > find /sys/fs/cgroup/ -name "dude*"
> > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c3.scope/dudemem
> > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c3.scope/dudecpu
> ```

Comment: I know how cgroups do that on linux however the issue is to do that at runtime ! I think using exec on docker we may update constraints